# How to get data from jquery input field?

Tags: ajax, django, jquery-ui

I use JQuery Datepicker and cannot get data from it.
In .html:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>&nbsp;</p>
```

In models.py:

```
class RecordModel(models.Model):
    ...
    Date = models.DateField(blank = False)
    ...
```

In forms.py:

```
class RecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    #There is no Date field
    ...
```

In views.py:

```
def doc(request, DocName):
    S = request.POST.get("Date") # error
```

Value of S in doc() function in views.py is "" (empty string), even if I choose date in a widget. How to get real data?

Comment: Is the first snippet (HTML) a custom code or generated by Django forms? I guess it's the former, in which case the value of this field can't be found in ``request.POST`` because the input doesn't have ``name`` attribute specified. I'd suggest attaching the Datepicker to the DateField (or is the problem here that ``Date`` field of the ModelForm is not being rendered?).

Comment: "Is the first snippet (HTML) a custom code" - yes. Thank you for the solution. "I'd suggest attaching the Datepicker to the DateField" - how to do it?

Comment: Is the Date field (from RecordForm) displayed? If so, the jQuery part in this case would be something like ``$( "#id_Date" ).datepicker();``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `name` attribute to submit data.

You are looking for a POST data keyed by `Date` but I don't see a `name=Date` anywhere.

It should be:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="Date"/>&nbsp;</p>
```